# Extract 7z file in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, 7zip, coldfusion-10

Can anyone help me by suggesting a function to extract a `.7z` file in ColdFusion? I use ColdFusion 10 and cfscript based code. Indeed we have the `cfzip` tag, but it only extracts `.zip` and `.jar` files.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cfexecute`, which unfortunately is not availble in `cfscript`, to execute the 7z extractor on your server and pass through the various commands to extract the file to a place of your choosing.

Luckily for you, it seems Raymond Camden has gone into it in some detail:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/2/21/Working-with-RARs-in-ColdFusion

Answer (score 0):

Function to unrar .rar file in given destination.. use cfexecute tag to run rar exe in command line

```
<cffunction name="Unrar" access="public" returnType="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="archivefile" type="string" required="true">     
    <cfargument name="destination" type="string" required="true">
    <cfset var exeName = "">
    <cfset var result = "">
    <cfset var errorresult = "">


    <cfif not fileExists(arguments.archivefile)>
        <cfthrow message="Unable to work with #arguments.arvhiefile#, it does not exist.">
    </cfif>

    <cfif findnocase(".rar",arguments.archivefile)>

        <cfset var exeName = expandpath("WinRAR\rar.exe")>
        <cfset var args = []>
        <cfif directoryExists(#arguments.destination#)>             
            <cfset args[1] = "x +o">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset directoryCreate(#arguments.destination#)>                
            <cfset args[1] = "x">
        </cfif>
        <cfset args[2] = arguments.archivefile>
        <cfset args[3] = "#arguments.destination#">         
    </cfif>
    <cfexecute name="#exeName#" arguments="#args#" variable="result" errorvariable="errorresult" timeout="99" />

    <cfif findNoCase("OK All OK", result)>
        <cfreturn true>
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn false>
    </cfif>        
</cffunction>
```